# Referencing in html to css and js files

Tags: javascript, html, heroku, tomcat, reference

My css and js functionality dont load properly in VSC.
When I go live, it seems that it cannot find the files.

[image: project directory tree]

only when I refer to it from the project root will it work in css.

```html
from src/main/webapp/    <script src="src/main/webapp/js/darkmode.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

in Intellij and Heroku web deployment it works from the webapp root:

```html
from webapp/    <script src="/js/darkmode.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

The same applies to .css files.

And then I am not even talking about referring to REST resources on heroku, as this will work on tomcat local but not on heroku web with the same adress.

Comment: I hope this is clear, will gladly elaborate or edit if needed :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use drag and drop mouse files from project to working file ( VS Studio)
Or using "~"

```
 <link href="~/Content/bootstrap-chosen.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

Comment: I will give this a try, do you mean in Intellij? -edit: just tried in vsc doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

It seems my problems in vsc where down to loading in a larger project with Java, when I loaded only the webapp folder then things worked properly !

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).